# Run a GitHub Action only when someone opens a PR

Tags: github, github-actions

Is there a way to run Github-Actions only when PR Opens.
I know there is a possibility to run workflow with `on = "pull_request"`. However it means the workflow will be triggered when someone opens PR, comments it, review and close. I would like to run it only once, when someone opens PR. I tried ENV_VAR but no luck. Perhaps events might be the way to go? https://developer.github.com/webhooks/#events

Answer (score 2):

Run a workflow when a Pull Request is Opened:

```
on:
  pull_request:
    types: [opened]
```

I think this should work.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/actions/bin/tree/master/filter#actor can be useful to filter before your action.